# How to make a double pointer argument automatic in a C function?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a simple function called make5 that makes every element in a 2d matrix equal to 5, shown below:

```
int make5(int r, int c, double **d)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      d[i][j] = 5;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to be able to run this function on different matrices, using the following calls:

```
make5(2, 3, a);
make5(2, 4, b);
```

where a and b have been declared as pointers to arrays of arrays.  But when I try this I keep getting a segmentation fault error.  How can I change make5 so I can run it on both a and b?

Comment: Did you allocate the space for `a` and/or `b`?

Comment: The pointers you pass to the function `make5()` should be pointing to some valid and sufficient memory.As long as you ensure that, Your code will work fine.

Comment: Can you show how you declared `a` and `b`?

Comment: Ahh that's the cause, I stuck an extra * in malloc, I hate when it's something that small.  Thank you guys.

Comment: To keep from typing mistakes in malloc always do `foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * number);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function works just fine. You must be allocating the memory incorrectly or passing wrong parameters to the function.

Working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int make5(int r, int c, double **d)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      d[i][j] = 5;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 3

int main(void)
{
  double** p = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(double*));
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    p[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(double));

  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      p[i][j] = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      printf("%f ", p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  make5(ROWS, COLS, p);

  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      printf("%f ", p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/UmfOq)):

```
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000
```