# Incompatible pointer type warnings in array of strings

Tags: c

I am trying out arrays of strings in C. I have a dictionary array of strings, that I add words to and then print out the array to see if it worked. The output works, as i think it should, printing the words in the array. But I get a number of warnings that I am unable to fix.

```
// 20 word dictionary
#define ROWS 20
#define WORD_LENGTH 10

char dictionary[ROWS][WORD_LENGTH];

void add_word(char **dict, int index, char *word) {
    dict[index] = word;
}

char *get_word(char **dict, int index) {
    return dict[index];
}

void print_dictionary(char **dict) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, get_word(dict, i));
    }
}

void test_dictionary() {
    add_word(dictionary, 0, "lorem");
    add_word(dictionary, 1, "ipsum");

    print_dictionary(dictionary);
}

int main() {
    test_dictionary();
}
```

The output of compiling this is,

```
p5.c: In function ‘test_dictionary’:
p5.c:54:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘add_word’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
p5.c:38:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
p5.c:55:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘add_word’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
p5.c:38:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
p5.c:57:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_dictionary’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
p5.c:46:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
```

I tried changing **dict to dict[ROWS][WORD_LENGTH] without much difference. Can you guys please explain how to declare this dictionary parameter. Thanks.

Edit: My compiler flags are, CFLAGS = -Wall -g.

Edit2: Changed the declarations to,

```
void add_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index, char *word) {
    dict[index] = word;
}

char *get_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index) {
    return dict[index];
}

void print_dictionary(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, get_word(dict, i));
    }
}
```

This gives a compilation error,

```
p5.c: In function ‘add_word’:
p5.c:42:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[10]’ from type ‘char *’
make[1]: *** [p5] Error 1
```

Thank you for all your help.

Ah! Figured it out!. Since it's a pointer, I need to use strcpy as suggested by @Jack.

```
void add_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index, char *word) {
    /*dict[index] = word;*/
    strcpy(dict[index], word);
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a double pointer argument automatic in a C function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364495/how-to-make-a-double-pointer-argument-automatic-in-a-c-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Root Cause:**

> **Arrays are not pointers!**

Note that there is no implicit conversion from `dict[][]` to `dict **` and hence the error. When you pass a array to a function, it decays as the pointer to its first element.In case of two dimensional array the first element is an array of single dimenion itself and so you need a pointer to an array and not an double pointer.

**Soultion:**

You need to modify your function prototype to match the *type* you are passing.

```
void add_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index, char *word);
void print_dictionary(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the functions to the above. But I am getting a different error now, about char[10] to char **.

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that you are really not passing a pointer to pointer, but an array of array. The difference is that memory is already allocated, and you cannot use the assignment operator "=" in add_word().

The correct signature would be

```
void add_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index, char *word)
```

and you must use a method like strcpy or strncpy

Comment: Thanks! I changed this but getting a different type error. See above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the size of the inner array, as you dereferencing it. So instead of:

```
void add_word(char **dict, int index, char *word)
```

You need:

```
void add_word(char dict[][WORD_LENGTH], int index, char *word)
```

And the same for `print_dictionary`.

The main confusion is that array of char **arrays** is not the same as array of char **pointers**.

Comment: I changed it to the above signature but now it gives a type error, char[10] to char *.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, your types are completely off.

The "minimum number of changes" fix is to just replace one line:

```
char* dictionary[ROWS];
```

Basically, you did create a memory block layouted as

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  ... c20
c21 c22 c23 c24 ... c40
c41 c42 ...
...
```

However, you USED it like a memory block of

```
charpointer1
charpointer2
charpointer3
...
```

It just appeared to work, and your actuallly allocated memory block was larger anyway, so it was even "safe" in the sense that nothing bad would ever have happened.

EDIT: your code would have "blown up" if you had ever tried to use your "dictionary" directly; accessing e.g. "dictionary[n]" to get the n-th word would have given you wrong results.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me figure out what I need to study further.